# Display Tag Struts 2 Export not showing PDF

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2, displaytag

I can enable export attribute in display table tag, but I am getting only CSV, Excel, XML. I want PDF and other rtf export formats too. I am using display tag 1.2 version. How to enable other attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [DisplayTag 1.2 Documentation](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/export.html):

> **Exporting data** - PDF
>
> Not enabled by default, 
>   set `export.pdf=true` in `displaytag.properties` 
>   and include the required IText jar in `WEB-INF/lib`